# DecodeError when reading Proto Buffer message from nanopb

Tags: c, flask, protocol-buffers, iot, nanopb

I implemented a small HttpClient for an IoT device and wanted to use Proto Buffer as a communication format. Because of the constraints of the platform I am using nanopb. That's the relevant code in C:

```
#include <pb_encode.h>
#include "device_data.pb.h"
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>

[...]
pb_MEvent m_event = pb_MEvent_init_zero;
uint8_t m_buffer[21];
pb_ostream_t stream = pb_ostream_from_buffer(m_buffer, 21);
pb_encode(&stream, pb_MEvent_fields, &m_event);

int httpCode = httpClient.POST(m_buffer, stream.bytes_written);
[...]
```

I created a small flask server which exposes an endpoint. When I try to decode the message, I get the following error: `google.protobuf.message.DecodeError: Error parsing message with type 'pb.MEvent'`

That the code for it:

```
from flask import Flask, request

from device_data_pb2 import MEvent

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/", methods = ['POST', "GET"])
def hello_world():
    m_event = MEvent()

    m_event.ParseFromString(request.data)
    print(m_event)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port= 5000)
```

I tried to use io.ByteStream and read it then and I also tried to encode the bytes with ASCII and UTF-8 but neither of that approaches worked.

Could you please help me find out, what is causing the problem? The error message is not that helpful.

### Update

This is the content fo the proto file:

```
syntax = "proto2";
package pb;

message MEvent {
    required float accelX = 1;
    required float accelY = 2;
    required float accelZ = 3;
    required float gyroX = 4;
    required float gyroY = 5;
    required float gyroZ = 6;
    required int64 msec = 7;
}
```

And here are some data points:

```
DATA:
0.16 -0.08 9.96 0.00 -0.00 0.02 0
HEX:
0d:98:d7:27:3e:15:bf:f7:ad:bd:1d:46:70:1f:41:25:b5:33:70:3b:2d

DATA:
0.16 -0.09 9.96 0.00 -0.00 0.02 0
HEX:
0d:cd:7d:20:3e:15:56:ab:bc:bd:1d:5f:6b:1f:41:25:79:22:a0:3b:2d


DATA:
0.15 -0.10 9.96 0.00 -0.00 0.02 0
HEX:
0d:89:0a:1e:3e:15:21:05:c4:bd:1d:de:52:1f:41:25:b5:33:70:3b:2d
```

Comment: Please include the message definition for `MEvent` from .proto file and a hex dump of the raw data in `request.data`.

Comment: I added the float and int data and their corresponding hex representation. I printed it on the board and at the flask server, there is no difference. So the communication between board and server works, it seems like there is a problem with the data itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> DATA: 0.16 -0.08 9.96 0.00 -0.00 0.02 0
> HEX: 0d:98:d7:27:3e:15:bf:f7:ad:bd:1d:46:70:1f:41:25:b5:33:70:3b:2d

I'm using the `nanopb/tests/raw_decode` to analyze this. Marc Gravell's [decode utility](https://protogen.marcgravell.com/decode) used to be great for this but for some reason it does not work very well for corrupted data anymore.

```
user@host:~/nanopb/tests$ echo 0d:98:d7:27:3e:15:bf:f7:ad:bd:1d:46:70:1f:41:25:b5:33:70:3b:2d \
| tr -d ':' | xxd -r -p | build/raw_decode/raw_decode

At 0: field tag 1, wire type 5 (32BIT), fixed32 value (4 bytes): 0x3e27d798
At 5: field tag 2, wire type 5 (32BIT), fixed32 value (4 bytes): 0xbdadf7bf
At 10: field tag 3, wire type 5 (32BIT), fixed32 value (4 bytes): 0x411f7046
At 15: field tag 4, wire type 5 (32BIT), fixed32 value (4 bytes): 0x3b7033b5
At 20: field tag 5, wire type 5 (32BIT)
ERROR: Failed to parse fixed32: io error
LATEST BYTES READ (21 to 21):
```

It appears your message is cut short.
The amount of buffer space you reserve on this line is not large enough:

> uint8_t m_buffer[21];

If you check the return value of `pb_encode()` it is probably also returning `false` and `stream.errmsg` indicates that the buffer is full.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! For some reason in the past, stream.bytes_written returned 21 and I took that as a constant. I reevaluated this and now it works.

Comment: Yeah, protobuf is a variable length format. Nanopb generates a `#define MEvent_size xxx` in the header that you can use for the buffer size, it is the maximum encoded size that message type will have.